# c# Pass Parameter from project to another project

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows desktop application using c# , my solution has 2 projects

the first one is a project that hold all the GUI and classes for a Login system (using SQL db) , after the a success login my function return the full data of the actual user :

```
private void Login(string User, string Pass)
{
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();
    Table = UserConnecction.Log_in(User, Pass);
    int Count = Table.Rows.Count;
    switch (Count)
    {
        case 1:
            User_info.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[0][0]);
            User_info.UserName = Table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            User_info.Password = Table.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            User_info.Email = Table.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            User_info.Pack = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[0][4]);
            MessageBox.Show("" + User_info.UserID);
            Main Main = new Main(User_info.UserName);
            Main.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();
            break;

        case 0:
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login ! ");
            break;

    }
}
```

And my second solution holds some functions that need the `ID` of the `connected user` , so I want basically to pass that parameter to the seonce project when the user login

I already tried to use the first project as a reference but it seems like you can only uses functions and classes and not passing a parameter cause it will always displays 0 !

Thank you !

Comment: do you have 2 Solutions or 2 Projects in 1 Solution?

Comment: Do you need two applications to talk to each other?

Comment: I have One solution that hold 2 projects (both  c#)

Comment: Are you using `Form` or `WPF`

Comment: @DDD Soft M using Form applications

Comment: What's the point of this kind of architecture? Why not put the login-stuff including the UI into a DLL which you can include?

Comment: @Rawitas Krungkaew Yes !

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar I don't think that would be very useful cause the application would be launched with more than once at the same desktop

Comment: @CruDy Why? You can prevent multiple starts easily. When the application is started show the login UI. If login was successful, continue your application, otherwise quit. What's hard about that? Maybe you should put some effort into explaining *why* you want that kind of architecture.

Comment: 2 application talking to each other can be done by using WCF :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx

Comment: @DDDSoft This is overkill in this case. Simple IPC through named pipes would be enough here.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar I want that architecture basically cause the first project while build the seconde project , like when the user login he will build a desktop application (.exe) that has the logged User ID

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar it is indeed overkill, but responding to the original question: it is quite easy to communicate between 2 applications.

Comment: @CruDy I don't get what you want, really. Well, go for DDD Soft's suggestion or use named pipes to communicate between both applications.

Comment: I have experience using NamedPipeServerStream - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5676899/1554116

Answer (score -1):

Your 'main' project is the form-application. You need to reference the second project by Add reference (and click project-tab) and check the project you need.

Then in your first project, in a button_click handler or something you can use:

```
   public void Button_loginHandler()
   {
       var x = new namespaceSecondProject.Class(constructor info);
   }
```

So if I have one project (the second project in your class):

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Username {get; set;}
        public string Password {get; set;}
        public datetime LastLoginDate {get;set;}

        public void SetLastLogin()
        {
            LastLoginDate = datetime.now;
       }
    }
}
```

in your first project (your windows forms): you can use:

```
var newUser = new TestProject.User{ Username = "me", Password = "you"};
```

And if you want to use a function it is

```
  newUser.SetLastLogin();
```

Pls note that this makes no sense, but hope to see that you can use classes and function like you want..

Comment: Yes ! but i want to be able to work with parameters value in the both projects

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: for example a Rat (remote acces tool) Njrat or spygate etc ... , when you build the server.exe it has the value of the server selected in the build option

Comment: I suggested this kind of architecture in the comments and it was rejected by the OP as "not very useful".