# C# Access process start information

Tags: c#, debugging, process, profiling

i no have idea if is possibile.
I want to access to process started and get information like Visual Studio.

for example, if i run my application, i can view variable value,
structure situation and more.

I would like to avoid the use of socket.

Example, this is my application:

I need to retrieve information about the actor's position, the lights, the CPU consumption and more

[image]

Comment: You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5676847/993547)?

Comment: yes @Patrick Hofman, Named Pipe is a good choice? i dont know this method. it's a news for me