# Delete Notifyicon ContextMenuStrip item from another exe file in c#

Tags: c#, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

I have 2 project in my solution on Visual Studio. First project (Winforms/Application) has got a notify icon with content menu strip like this:

```cs
private void TrayMenuContext()
{
    notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Test1", null, MenuTest1_Click);
    notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Test2", null, MenuTest2_Click);
    notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Exit", null, MenuExit_Click);
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var mi = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        mi?.Invoke(notifyIcon1, null);
    }
}
```

And the second project (Winforms/Application) has got a button like this:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
    * How should I code here to delete the notify icon content menu strip item
    * in first application named "Test2"?
    */
}
```

When I click the button, I want to delete the "Test2" menu item in the first application notify icon content menu strip. But unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea about it. Moreover, I do not know if such a thing is possible. However, the extraordinary features of .Net encourage me.

Comment: You can use one of many IPC methods to communicate with the other app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between two different applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676847/communication-between-two-different-applications)

Comment: @Sinatr - Absolutely you are right. But this a console application example and I did not implement it into the my application.